# How to add new kits to Qt Creator

Tags: c++, windows, qt

How do I add more kits like MinGW to a Qt installation?

Just to help people, I'm gonna answer this here for Windows, but I'd like to know for Linux too.

Comment: 1 - This is not really a coding question. 2 - MinGW is the default used by Qt on Windows. 3 - Qt Creator is only an IDE (yes you can use Qt without it). If you have specific compiler/linker that you want to use, you just have to configure QtCreator to use them instead (as for any proper IDE).

Comment: But for the already supported kits, you have an application usually provided with your Qt installation called _Qt Maintenance Tool_ which is meant to select which components you want to install/update/remove.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the Qt uninstaller in Windows, launch it, but instead of uninstalling it, select new kits to install.

Comment: Actually there is a **Qt Maintenance Tool** application usually (default) installed along with Qt which is exactly meant for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, the repos method of sudo apt install... never seems to work, they don't install kits, which is a bit useless, so download and install the online installer for Linux/Mac/Windows [here](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/)